# Gulp / Laravel Elixir - Deleting a local variable in strict mode error

Tags: javascript, laravel, gulp, laravel-elixir

I am working on a Laravel 5 project on a Windows machine and just encountered an error while attempting to run `gulp`-

```
events.js:85
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
            ^
SyntaxError: c:/Users/Benjamin/PhpstormProjects/essex-youth-footbal/resources/assets/bower/jquery/dist/vendor.js: Deleting local variable in strict mode (13795:23316)
  13793 | //
```

Here is the entry in the gulpfile.js where this is being thrown:

```
mix.scripts([
        '/assets/bower/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js',
        '/assets/bower/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js',
        '/assets/js/main.js',
        '/assets/bower/bootbox/bootbox.js',
        '/assets/bower/vue/dist/vue.min.js',
        '/assets/bower/mustache/mustache.min.js',
        '/assets/bower/bootstrap-multiselect/dist/js/bootstrap-multiselect.js',
        '/assets/js/redactor.js',
        '/assets/js/vendor/redactor/fontcolor.js',
        '/assets/js/vendor/redactor/fontsize.js',
        '/assets/js/vendor/redactor/imagemanager.js',
        '/assets/js/vendor/redactor/video.js',
        '/assets/bower/remarkable-bootstrap-notify/dist/bootstrap-notify.min.js',
        '/assets/bower/jquery.maskedinput/dist/jquery.maskedinput.min.js',
        '/assets/bower/moment/min/moment.min.js',
        '/assets/bower/eonasdan-bootstrap-datetimepicker/build/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js',
        '/assets/bower/raphael/raphael-min.js',
        '/assets/bower/morrisjs/morris.min.js'
    ], 'public/js/vendor.js', 'resources');
```

I also noticed that any merged JS files that ARE created have `"use strict"` prepended to the code.

`gulp` is working fine in another project on the same computer and this project's gulp configuration works fine on another computer. Any ideas what might be causing this?

Comment: Are you using an elevated console in one and not the other?

Comment: @MatthewRath no. I may have found a solution thanks to JeffreyWay on Laracasts, hope to test later today. May be due to an update to Elixir.

Comment: @NightMICU care to post your solution?

Comment: @stueynet honestly I cannot recall just what the solution was. I may have just needed to run bower install again, I recall it being something trivial like that. What I can say for sure was that it wasn't related to any of my code, just a dependency issue somewhere.